# How to generate sequence when start is greater than stop

Tags: r, vector, seq

I would like to generate sequence somewhat like `10, 7, 4, 1`

`seq` function can't do it (start is greater than stop). What function can do this? I prefer not to loop over my sequence (it is going to be very time consuming as I have a large number of vectors needed to be processed like that).

```
> seq(10, 0, by=3)
```

> Error in seq.default(10, 0, by = 3) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Answer (score 5):

```
seq(from = 10, to = 0, by = -3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be creating a logical vector and subsetting.

```
n <- 3
(10:0)[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n - 1))]
#[1] 10  7  4  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
10 - 0:3 * 3
#[1] 10  7  4  1
```

Or to get integers (not floating point numbers) out:

```
typeof(10 - 0:3 * 3)
#[1] "double"

10L - 0:3 * 3L
#[1] 10  7  4  1
```